# How to run a script using django rest framework integrated with react

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs

I am trying to summon a script that sends an email when you press a button in react, my problem is that i haven't found any good way to do so. I currently have the function on a views file such as follows

```
def sender(request):    
    me = "username"
    my_password = r"my password"
    you = info.__str__

    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = "Alert"
    msg['From'] = me
    msg['To'] = you

    html = '<html><body><p>hello world</p></body></html>'
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

    msg.attach(part2)

    s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com')
    s.login(me, my_password)

    s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
```

and import it on the url file:

```
urlpatterns = [path('send/', views.sender)]
```

I am using axios on the react front with the following code

```
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/send/')
```

and it gives me this error when I try to access run it

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: What is `function`? View should return a response object.

Comment: Provide the code related to function. We cannot attempt to troubleshoot without knowing what your function is attempting to do beyond your verbiage.

Comment: I added the function in an edit, but i dont think it was what it was causing the issues.

Comment: The error message says that some function was passed where there should be a class with encode attribute. As a starting point you need to post full traceback so we can establish what was this function and where it was used.